# Reset the Execution Transcript in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Execution transcript is showing very sensitive information in google script. How can we clear/reset/disable it.

One solution is there like invoke dummy script every minute. Please tell me anyother solution for this problem

Comment: Please consider providing more information. I'm not sure I understand what you mean, based on the information you provided.

Comment: I am using jdbc connection to my MS sql db. If you execute any query from google app script, All information like server ip, username and psw is shown in execution transcript log.

Comment: remove logging from the source code

Comment: Hi, App script automatically log "Execution transcript" and we dont have control on it.